# How to set an environment variable on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: tensorflow, ubuntu

According to the [deespeech documentation](https://deepspeech.readthedocs.io/en/latest/TRAINING.html#recommendations) to avoid this error related to tensorflow I have to proceed as follows but I don't know how to set an environment variable. Could you explain me the steps to follow? I use ubuntu 18.04.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can type `TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH=true` in you terminal before running your program.

You can also add `export TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH=true` in ~/.bashrc and it will load automatically when new terminal will open